# Batch File - Random 10 Digit Number

Tags: batch-file, random, cmd

I'm looking for a batch file code that will generate a random 10 digit number and will show up to the user using the batch file... (I'm making a generator)

Comment: It doesn't look like you're making anything, more like you want somebody else to make it. Try posting your code first then ask for help with it.

Comment: If you want to write a Batch file that _generate_ a 10-digit random number, then you should read [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators); I suggest you to use a 32-bits Linear-Feedback Shift Register (LFSR) method, that is very simple to implement in a Batch file.

Answer (score 2):

Or in a loop:

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /L %%i In (1,1,10) Do (Set/A _=!random! %%10&Set num=!num!!_!)
Echo=%num%
Pause
```

Comment: Im making a GENERATOR (not for numbers) I just need a number generator to help, It sounds wierd ik, but thanks for the answer

Comment: It is common practice when someone provides the solution you require to mark it accordingly as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set /a num1=%random% %% 10 
Set /a num2=%random% %% 10 
Echo %num1%%num2%
```

Gives you a two digit random number. So do above 10 times. See `set /?` for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set /a num1=%random% %% 10 

Set /a num2=%random% %% 10 

Set /a num3=%random% %% 10 

Set /a num4=%random% %% 10 

Set /a num5=%random% %% 10 

Set /a num6=%random% %% 10 

Set /a num7=%random% %% 10 

Set /a num8=%random% %% 10 

Set /a num9=%random% %% 10 

Set /a num10=%random% %% 10 

echo %num1%%num2%%num3%%num4%%num5%%num6%%num7%%num8%%num9%%num10%
```

Comment: Hmmm - doesn't look very random :/

Comment: @Stephan sorry, try it now.

Comment: looks very much like Noodles answer now.

Comment: no because his would only do (randomnumberhere)(randomnumberhere).   Mine would do (randomnumberhere)(randomnumberhere)(randomnumberhere)(randomnumberhere)(randomnumberhere)(randomnumberhere)(randomnumberhere)(randomnumberhere)(randomnumberhere)(randomnumberhere). His is a 2 digit whereas mine is a 10 digit like asked.

Answer (score 0):

just to add another possibility:

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "num="
For /L %%i In (1,1,10) Do (Set "num=!num!!random:~-1!")
Echo=%num%
```